# Google Sheets ImportXML Error: Imported XML content cannot be parsed

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to import stock suggestions into a spreadsheet and have successfully done so from 3 websites, but I am struggling with the 4th.

```
 =IMPORTXML("https://www.tipranks.com/stocks/amzn/price-target","//h3[@class='client-components-stock-research-analysts-analyst-consensus-style__buy'")
```

Is the command I'm using to try to pull the tag under "Analyst Consensus Rating" from https://www.tipranks.com/stocks/amzn/price-target. But I keep getting:

> Error Imported XML content can not be parsed.``` Tips for what I'm doing wrong would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Google Sheets does not support web scraping of JavaScript controlled elements. you can easily check it by disabling JS for a given site and only what's left visible can be scraped. unfortunately, in your case, that's nothing:

[image: 0]